# QT: Generate a bar graph in a headless AMI Server. Cannot start X Display

Tags: qt, amazon-ec2

I'm doing some processing on an Amazon Linux EC2 AWS server. When something goes wrong I need to send an email with a bar graph. I want to generate a bar graph myself, and I'm doing so by using QPainter and QImage. I'm developing an example application to simply generate the bar graph, right now. So what I do is I develop on my laptop and when I have something that works upload the code to the EC2 server and compile it there. Then run the resulting application in the server.

However, here is the hiccup. When I tried to draw text using QPainter, the program in my laptop crashes. This is because I use a QCoreApplication instead of QApplication in my main.cpp.

So I change to QApplication which fixes the problem. I upload the code to the server and compile it. Then when I try to run it, I get:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
```

This is, of course, because the server is headless. 
My question is: is there something I can install in the server that would allow me to fully use QPainter's capabilities?

Edit:

My main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "../../CommonClasses/DataAnalysis/BarGrapher/bargrapher.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Setup
    qreal W = 1024;
    qreal H = 768;

    // A fictional data set;
    QList<qreal> ds1;
    ds1 << 50 << 500 << 368 << 198;

    QStringList descs;
    descs << "Item 1";
    descs << "A somewhat long and complex description";
    descs << "Item 2";
    descs << "Item Another";

    // The actual bar graph
    BarGrapher bg;
    bg.configureGraphText(W,H,descs,"Some sort of label","The title of this damn thing");
    BarGrapher::DataSet ds;
    ds << ds1;
    QImage result = bg.generateGraph(ds);

    qWarning() << "ERROR" << bg.getError();

    result.save("mytest.png");
    qWarning() << "DONE";

    return a.exec();
}
```

My bargrapher.cpp

```
#include "bargrapher.h"

const qreal BarGrapher::PROYECTION_FACTOR = 0.707106;
const qreal BarGrapher::LEFT_MARGIN  = 0.1;
const qreal BarGrapher::RIGHT_MARGIN = 0.04;
const qreal BarGrapher::TOP_MARGIN   = 0.08;

BarGrapher::BarGrapher()
{

}


void BarGrapher::configureGraphText(qreal width, qreal height, const QStringList &xItems, const QString &ylabel, const QString &title){
    graphTitle = title;
    W = width;
    H = height;
    itemDescriptions = xItems;
    yAxisText = ylabel;
}


QImage BarGrapher::generateGraph(const DataSet &dataSet){

    QImage graph(W,H,QImage::Format_RGB888);
    error = "";

    // Making sure that the data is coherent.
    if (dataSet.isEmpty()){
        error = "No data was presented";
        return graph;
    }
    if (dataSet.size() > 2){
        error = "Cannot have more than two data sets, passed " + QString::number(dataSet.size());
        return graph;
    }

    qint32 numItems = dataSet.first().size();
    for (qint32 i = 0; i < dataSet.size(); i++){
        if (numItems != dataSet.at(i).size()){
            error = "All data sets must be the same size: " + QString::number(numItems) + " however data set " + QString::number(i) + " has " + QString::number(dataSet.at(i).size());
            return graph;
        }
    }

    if (!itemDescriptions.isEmpty()){
        if (numItems != itemDescriptions.size()){
            error = "The number of item descriptios (" + QString::number(itemDescriptions.size()) + ") must coincide with the numer of points in the data set (" + QString::number(numItems) + ")";
            return graph;
        }
    }
    else{
        for (qint32 i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
            itemDescriptions << QString::number(i);
        }
    }

    // The font to be used
    QFont textFont("Mono");
    textFont.setPixelSize(10);
    //QFont titleFont("Mono",16,QFont::Bold);

    // Calculating margins to get the effective graph area.
    qreal XAxisLength = (1.0 - LEFT_MARGIN - RIGHT_MARGIN)*W;
    qreal DW = XAxisLength/(qreal)(numItems);

    // Calculating the effective graph area due to the text items.
    qreal Th = 0.1*H;
    qreal GH = (1.0-TOP_MARGIN)*H - Th;
    qreal xOffset = LEFT_MARGIN*W;
    qreal yOffset = TOP_MARGIN*H;

    // --------------- Commence drawing -----------------------
    QPainter painter(&graph);

    // The background
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(226,226,226)));
    painter.drawRect(0,0,W,H);

    // Drawing the axis;
    QPen pen;
    pen.setColor(QColor(0,0,0));
    pen.setWidth(2);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));

    painter.drawLine(xOffset,yOffset+GH,xOffset + XAxisLength,yOffset+GH);
    painter.drawLine(xOffset,yOffset,xOffset,yOffset+GH);

    // Drawing the X Axis text
    painter.setFont(textFont);
    for (qint32 i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
        QRectF rectF(xOffset + i*DW,yOffset+GH,DW,Th);
        painter.drawText(rectF,itemDescriptions.at(i));
    }

    return graph;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.  The errors you're seeing are what I might expect if you were trying to use a `QPixmap` rather than a `QImage`.

Comment: Added the full code. But I don't use QPixmap. And the problem, to me, has to do with the fact that drawing text requires a "connection" (don't know how to describe it) to the window system, which is not present in the Amazon Server

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question slightly.  Can you explain what happens when you use `QCoreApplication` rather than `QApplication` -- that seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I does? My program crashes on painter.drawText(rectF,itemDescriptions.at(i));

Comment: try with QGuiApplication instead QApplication.

Comment: Same thing. Thanks though

Comment: Is [`Xvfb`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) available on the AWS server?  If so it might serve as a possible solution.  Or, more specifically, [`xvfb-run`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xvfb-run.1.html).